Lights out problem, a try at a combinatorial solution
Reading through Pranav Sriram's Olympiad combinatorics book, I stumbled upon this problem (chapzer 2, exercise 9):

On each square of a chessboard is a light which has two states- on or off. A move consists of choosing a square and changing the state of the bulbs in that square and in its neighboring squares (squares that share a side with it). Show that starting from any configuration we can make finitely many moves to reach a point where all the bulbs are switched off

I tried solving it, and got stuck on a part which I just can't get pass. Googling the problem, I learned it is recognized as the "Lights out" problem. Most of the solutions online use linear algebra though, which is a topic I have almost no experience with.
My purely combinatorial argument started like this:
Iff we can get from any configuration to a configuration in which all lights are turned off, we can get to any configuration from the one with all lights off also. For convenience, let's prove that we can start from all bulbs turned off and get to any configuration by only using each switch at most once.
In each configuration, each one of n^2 bulbs (supposing we are given a n x n grid) is either turned on or off. So there are 2^(n^2) possible distinct configurations for the bulbs.
For each one of the switches, we may turn it on or off. There are also n^2 switches so we can have at most 2^(n^2) possible configurations we can obtain with these switch combinations.
To prove that we can reach all bulb configurations, we must say that for each two distinct switch configurations the final bulb configuration is also distinct. If this is true, our result is also true.
Now, let's suppose that some two configurations of switches are different but they result in the same bulb configuration. Let these switch configurations be A and B. For each switch flipped on in B, flip it back off and flip it in A. This results in all switches being turned off in B but some switches being turned on in A, but they both result in the same bulb configuration (namely the one where no bulbs are turned on).
So basically the only thing left to disprove is:
There exists a switch configuration A in which at least one switch is flipped on and all the bulbs are turned off.
I am confident this statement is true, I think my reasoning was good and that I always took steps with equivivalent reasoning. Any guess how one could attack this last statement?

You can try to prove that it is possible to turn all the lights off if the starting configuration has exactly 1 light on.

Can you provide a proper citation to the book, following our guidelines?  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Can you provide the exercise number, or chapter & section number, or page number where this appears?

If the claim is correct then you may need to use $8$ in the proof, as I think it may not be correct for a $5\times5$ chessboard.

@Henry This is correct. Do you think the rest of my proof is alright, though? Namely, that the statement to be proven and the statement I ended up with are equivalent?

This seems quite difficult. It is tempting to try to decompose the 8 × 8 board into 4 × 4 sub-boards, but lights out on a 4 × 4 is not always solvable! The 2 × 2 and 2 × 4 boards are solvable (see Jaap's website). I've seen an earlier problem about proving that a $(2^n-1)\times(2^n-1)$ lights-out board is always solvable, and that one could be solved by decomposition into smaller boards, plus induction.

I can confirm that your reasoning is all correct. Still, I do not see a path to a solution.

Well, I guess it was worth a shot. Thank you for your time.
